# Recordset for todays date using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql

hopefully this is an easy one.

I have a query that I want to produce results for todays date only based on a column (record_date)  that uses CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

so my query goes...

```
Select columns FROM fields WHERE table.record_date = DATE_SUB(NOW());
```

This is throwing up an error... :(

---

Thanks for you help....So i tried....

SELECT * FROM `daily_record` WHERE `record_date` = CURDATE()

but it yielded no result.

Here is a sample of the data in the column i am searching...

2011-03-31 11:28:37,
2011-03-31 11:28:37,
2011-03-31 11:28:37,
.....

Does it matter that the time is also saved?

Comment: What is the error ? The pasted code is missing a ) before the ;

Comment: I noticed the missing bracket :)... 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```
Select columns FROM fields WHERE table.record_date > CURDATE();
```

Comment: Yes (if I understand well your comment). It's like if you were doing `2011-03-31 17:09:33` (current time) `> 2011-03-31 00:00:00` (first second of current day)

Answer (score 0):

DATE_SUB() is for subtracting an interval from a date in MySQL. You've got DATE_SUB(now()), but don't specify an interval

It should be something like

```
... DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

so MySQL's complaining about the unexpected `)`, because of the missing interval.

If you want to convert 'now' into a date, you can simply use `CURDATE()`, or `DATE(now())`

Comment: Thanks for you help!

I tried this...

SELECT * FROM `daily_record` WHERE `record_date` = CURDATE()

but it yielded no result.

Here is a sample of the data in the column i am searching...

2011-03-31 11:28:37
2011-03-31 11:28:37
2011-03-31 11:28:37
.....

Does it matter that the time is also saved?

Comment: Yes. When comparing a plain date to a full datetime, mysql "up converts" the date to being at 00:00:00 time. So the hours/minutes/seconds of "now" would have to match exactly the timestamp in the record you're comparing against.